# Why won't my ocelot turn into a cat?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I used the bamboo forest seed that I have knowing that I would be able to find beautiful animals such as ocelots and parrots. I put the world into creative so I could build a house. When I spawned in I wnet straight to the spot I wanted to build my house and I found an ocelot. So I thought, Hmm.. 
how about I tame it. I filled up my inventory with raw cod and leaded the ocelot to fencepost. I fed it about two of the stacks in creative and it wouldn't turn into a cat. Then I thought to myself maybe I would have to do it in survival. So about three stacks later the ocelot still wouldn't turn into a cat. So I decided to unlead it and after all the ten stacks of cod where gone it still wouldn't turn into a cat! Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?! It even gave me heart particles and everything! I was close to it too so its not like I wasn't effecting it.

Answer (score 3):

Ocelots no longer turn into cats as of the Village and Pillage update where you now get tamable cats from the stray cats that spawn in villages, which stray cat taming works the way old ocelot taming worked.

As for Ocelots now, you can still feed them with fish, however doing so will only make them gain trust with your player (it won't be scared and run away from you anymore), and won't turn it into a cat.

Answer (score 2):

In recent updates ocelots keep their skin when you tame them, this was introduced because you can find stray cats in villages